# How to get JavaFX WebView to continue to load page with self-signed certificate with JavaFX 14/HTTP2/JDK-8211308

Tags: ssl, javafx, webview, http2, self-signed

Can anyone tell me how I can continue to display web pages using a self-signed https certificate in WebView after updating to JavaFX 14?

Prior to JavaFX 14 we have been handling this by implementing a custom `TrustHandler` and `HostnameVerifier` using `HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultSSLSocketFactory` and `HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultHostnameVerifier`.

When I switch to JavaFX 14 and WebView tries to load the self-signed web pages

- they do not load,
- the custom TrustHandler code is no longer called, and
- I get this back from `webView.getEngine().getLoadWorker().getException()`:

  ```
    java.lang.Throwable: SSL handshake failed  
     at javafx.web/javafx.scene.web.WebEngine$LoadWorker.describeError(WebEngine.java:1431)  
     at javafx.web/javafx.scene.web.WebEngine$LoadWorker.dispatchLoadEvent(WebEngine.java:1370)  
     at javafx.web/javafx.scene.web.WebEngine$PageLoadListener.dispatchLoadEvent(WebEngine.java:1231)  
     at javafx.web/com.sun.webkit.WebPage.fireLoadEvent(WebPage.java:2514)  
     at javafx.web/com.sun.webkit.WebPage.fwkFireLoadEvent(WebPage.java:2359)  
     at javafx.web/com.sun.webkit.network.URLLoaderBase.twkDidFail(Native Method)  
     at javafx.web/com.sun.webkit.network.HTTP2Loader.notifyDidFail(HTTP2Loader.java:624)  
     at javafx.web/com.sun.webkit.network.HTTP2Loader.lambda$didFail$18(HTTP2Loader.java:606)  
     at javafx.web/com.sun.webkit.network.HTTP2Loader.lambda$callBackIfNotCanceled$10(HTTP2Loader.java:437)  
     at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$10(PlatformImpl.java:428)  
     at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:391)  
     at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$11(PlatformImpl.java:427)  
     at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:96)  
     at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)  
     at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$runLoop$3(WinApplication.java:174)  
     at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:830)
  ```

I have no problem with JavaFX 13.0.2, but it fails with 14 or 14.0.1. 
Curiously there is also no problem even with JavaFX 14 if I run against OpenJDK up to 11.0.2, but the problem occurs from 12 up to 15ea20.

From looking through the release notes for both JavaFX and the JDK, the only likely cause looks to me to be [JDK-8211308 - Support HTTP/2 in WebView](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=JDK-8211308). 
This implies moving away from using JDK's `URLConnection` class and I'm guessing that this could cause it to then no longer use my custom TrustHandler.

If I'm correct, then I need to know how to continue to use my custom TrustHandler for connections initiated below WebView, but I can't see how to do that from the API in java.net.http.

Alternately the enhancement description mentions:

> a Runtime property will be provided to fallback to legacy HTTP API

but I can find no other mention of this - how do I use this fallback? 
Or is there some alternate way to get the WebView to allow the self-signed certificates? 
Or am I wrong about what has changed with JavaFX 14 and there is some other solution?

Comment: If you are deploying your app as jlinked module, it is necessary to require the needed crypto modules.  See [Modular Java 13 / JavaFx WebWiew fails to display when jlinked](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60092805/1155209), which recommends the following requirement: `requires jdk.crypto.cryptoki;`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found that `-Dcom.sun.webkit.useHTTP2Loader=false` disables HTTP2 support, and fixes the issue.

Comment: The `com.sun` properties are internal implementations, not part of the public API.  Support for them could be dropped in future releases without warning.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to make `-Dcom.sun.webkit.useHTTP2Loader=false`,
you can make it also easily runtime like this:

```
static {
            System.setProperty("com.sun.webkit.useHTTP2Loader", "false");
       }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your assumption on the switch-to-HTTP2 being (part of) the problem, is correct.

### TL;DR

- newer JavaFX use `HTTP2Loader` by default, which ignores `HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultSSLSocketFactory(sc.getSocketFactory())`.
  Instead/additionally do `SSLContext.setDefault(yourSslContext)`.
- the "runtime property to fallback to legacy HTTP API" is `-Dcom.sun.webkit.useHTTP2Loader={true,false}`

### Related JDK bugs:

- [JDK-8246215 : WebView does not care "HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultSSLSocketFactory()" (Closed)](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=8246215)
- [JDK-8242077 : Add information about HTTP/2 and HttpClient usage in WebEngine](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=8242077)

  - relevant workaround in comments:

    > For information, I was able to work-around the issue by adding
    >
    > ```java
    > SSLContext.setDefault(sc);
    > ```
    >
    > where "sc" is the SSLContext created with the [oft-copy-pasted all-trusting] TrustManager.

### relevant sections in JavaFX code

I've just spent multiple hours stepping through `WebEngine.load(..)` in a Debugger.
The JavaFX version I am working on is `org.openjfx 17.0.2` from Maven.
I'm documenting my results to help travelers from the future.

- `WebEngine.open(..)` delegates to `WebPage.open` which does its loading in
  `com.sun.webkit.network.NetworkContext#fwkLoad(..)`
- `NetworkContext` has a flag `useHTTP2Loader`

  - defaults to true on `System.getProperty("java.version") >= 12`
  - overridden via VM-option `-Dcom.sun.webkit.useHTTP2Loader={true,false}`
- `com.sun.webkit.network.HTTP2Loader` has a `private final static HTTP_CLIENT` created by a `jdk.internal.net.http.HttpClientBuilderImpl`.

  - this builder *could* receive an `SSLContext`, but the HTTP2Loader implementation doesn't provide one, so it falls back to `SSLContext.getDefault() -> SSLContext.getInstance("Default")` -> `private static volatile SSLContext defaultContext`
  - `HttpsUrlConnection` is never touched/queried by the `HTTP2Loader`
  - thus, the HTTP2Loader, and thus JavaFX WebEngine, *always* uses the global default `SSLContext`
- the oft-copy-pasted `// Create a trust manager that does not validate certificate chains`-snippet sets
  `HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultSSLSocketFactory(sc.getSocketFactory())`

  - as mentioned in JDK-8242077, the only way to configure HTTP2Loader is to override the global default SSLContext:

    ```java
    SSLContext.setDefault( <your-context-with-alltrusting-TrustManager> );
    ```