# JavaFX WebView HTTP2Loader set custom HostnameVerifier

Tags: java, javafx, webview, http2, hostname-verifier

As described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73802321), when trying to accept self-signed certificates with the JavaFX WebView, the `HTTP2Loader` ignores method calls like

- `HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultSSLSocketFactory()`
- `HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultHostnameVerifier()`

While there is a workaround to accept self-signed certificates by setting the default `SSLContext` via `SSLContext.setDefault()` and injecting an all-trusting trust manager (which replaces `HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultSSLSocketFactory()`), I can't find a way to set a custom HostnameVerifier (i.e. replacing `HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultHostnameVerifier()`). Is there a way to do this, or is the only possible option not to use the `HTTP2Loader`?