# Cannot start program created with jpackage

Tags: java, javafx, jetty, jlink, jpackage

Hello everyone I am new using jpackage and I am building a java aplicaction with JavaFx framework and I added a Websocket server (using org.eclipse.jetty.websocket and org.eclipse.jetty dependencies) but the application does not start when I double click to the .exe.
I am using  the following dependencies in my pom file to add the websocket server:

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
            <artifactId>jetty-server</artifactId>
            <version>11.0.15</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
            <artifactId>jetty-servlet</artifactId>
            <version>11.0.15</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty.websocket</groupId>
            <artifactId>websocket-jetty-api</artifactId>
            <version>11.0.15</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty.websocket</groupId>
            <artifactId>websocket-jetty-server</artifactId>
            <version>11.0.15</version>
        </dependency>
```

The application was made in IntelliJ with java 20 and is working fine when i debug and I can interact with the graphical interface and I can connect to the websocket server but when I create  app image (.exe) with the following commands:

```
jlink --verbose --output runtime --module-path "$Env:JAVA_HOME/jmods" --add-modules javafx.base,javafx.controls,javafx.fxml,javafx.graphics,javafx.media,javafx.swing,javafx.web,java.base,java.desktop,java.instrument,java.logging,java.naming,java.net.http,java.scripting,java.sql,java.xml,jdk.unsupported,jdk.crypto.ec,jdk.accessibility,jdk.management.jfr --strip-native-commands --no-header-files --no-man-pages --strip-debug --compress=1
```

```
jpackage --verbose --type app-image --runtime-image runtime --input ../../target/libs --module-path ../../target/mods --module $ModuleAndMainClass --dest . --name $AppName --vendor $Vendor --resource-dir resources --java-options "-XshowSettings:all" --icon resources/$AppName.ico
```

I get the .exe application successfully but when I double click to the .exe, the process opens but ends immediately without warning or errors and when I create the .exe without websocket and without  org.eclipse.jetty, org.eclipse.websocket dependencies, the .exe runs successfully and I can interact with the graphical interface created with Javafx.

I am using Jdk 20.0.2 with javafx framework 20.0.2 and I have installed Javafx jmod in the path %JAVA_HOME%/jmods and I tried the following:

1. I tried install JavaxFx 20.0.2 framework from libs, copying the .jar files to the %JAVA_HOME%\lib folder
2. I tried clear cache memory
3. I tried reinstall Java and JavaFx 20.0.2
4. I tried disable antivirus when I execute Jpackage and Jlink commands
5. I tried clear maeven packages repository.
6. I have already validated that I only have a single version of Java installed(20.0.2)
   7.I have already validated that the packages (jmod) are added to the destination folder where the .exe is located, I even copied them manually but the problem persists.
7. I tried manually downloading javafx jmod packages to include the folder path in the --module-path parameter of the jLink command.

My system environment look fine: JAVA_HOME is the path of my jdk 20 installation folder and the Path has %JAVA_HOME%\bin
After that the problem still persists and I have the following questions:

1. What do I have to include in jlink or jpackage so that I can create the application image and run it with javafx and websocket server (org.eclipse.jetty)?
2. How can I validate the log of the application when it starts if it automatically closes?, Does Java have a way to monitor the execution of an .exe created with jpackage?
3. How can I verify that the runtime that is included in the application image can load all the necessary packages for the application to start?
   Any thoughts will be greatly appreciated.
   Best

Comment: "I have already validated that the packages (jmod) are added to the destination folder where the .exe is located" FWIW, .jmod files are only used as input for jlink, they can not be used as runtime dependencies.

Comment: Is your application modular? (i.e. do you have your own `module-info` file?) You are using `jlink` with `--add-modules` to add all the JDK modules, but you should only have to add the main module of your application.

Comment: I see you're also using `--input ../../target/libs`, are there extra jar files or native libraries that need to be added to the application?

Comment: If your websocket connections are using tls, you may [require cryptoki](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60081037/modular-java-13-javafx-webwiew-fails-to-display-when-jlinked).

Comment: You're most likely missing cryptographic modules in the custom run-time image and that is leading to failed SSL handshakes. See Q&A linked by jewelsea for more information. Also see https://stackoverflow.com/q/73590370/6395627 and its duplicates.

Comment: See also [Java FX Application with Jpackage not work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70456027/java-fx-application-with-jpackage-not-work)

Answer (score 4):

> How can I validate the log of the application when it starts if it automatically closes?, Does Java have a way to monitor the execution of an .exe created with jpackage?

You can try running jpackage with `--win-console`, and then running the application from the console to see if any error message is printed.

> How can I verify that the runtime that is included in the application image can load all the necessary packages for the application to start?

Create the runtime image without the `--strip-native-commands` option. That will result in a runtime image that includes the `java` launcher. You can then use that launcher to try and launch the application manually, by manually specifying the module path and main module.